# Is there any documentation for www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1 REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, content-builder

I'm trying to send Content Builder emails via the REST API and the best option looks like the 'www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1' endpoint. But there is little documentation on the API web site for it.

I can use the '/messaging/v1/rest' resource to see the available options but without knowing what to POST to them its hopeless.

Any help would be really appreciated. I'm sure I can't be the only person wanting to do this.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [POST /messaging/v1/](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm)

Comment: From what I can see this is for sending a single transactional email. I need to be able to send from a Data Extension.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the developer doc for the REST API https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm